# Swift - instance of backgroundColor not working

Tags: swift, uiview, uicolor

If I set up an image in the Image/Image View of the Attributes Inspector the following subsequent call does not work:

```
picture.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

If I setup the image in the code, such as in viewDidAppear, it does.

Am I missing something, is this a quirk and how do I get it to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work. But you can't see it in some cases. 
For example: in the following image I have change the background color and set it to aspect fit. The gap between the two appears in green. So the image must have some transparency to it in order to see the background color.

1. Image with white background

   [image: white background]
2. Image with transparent background

   [image: Transparent]

Edit: 
This is how I changed the background color

```
  @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picture.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
  }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am getting. Surely there must be ways of doing this that work rather than resorting to work arounds?

Comment: If the image is not transparent, you cannot change its background. In my picture the background is white. You need to edit the image in editor and remove the background.

Comment: You are absolutely spot on although find this illogical. Have slapped a completely transparent image in the Attributes Inspector and now it does as instructed when I issue subsequent commands in the code. Many thanks.